# App Notifications API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I want to use this API in my iPhone App so that App will post a notification to the user:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/
I implemented it in my App:
Was able to get the correct permission: FB_Permission_manage_notifications
**but could not get the call to work:**
Any ideas? 
(I get this respond:{"data":[],"summary":[]}

```
    NSDictionary * params = @{ @"access_token" : [[FBSession activeSession] accessToken], @"template" : @"this is a test", @"href" : @"www.blabla.com"};
    NSLog(@"%@",params);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/766042719/notifications"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];


    [httpClient getPath:@"" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSString* mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",mystring);
   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error);

   }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using App Access Token, instead of User Access Token. Basic permission is enough already, so it's not related to 'FB_Permission_manage_notifications'

As documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/:

> Apps can send notifications to any existing user that has authorized
> the app. **No special or extended permission is required**.
>
> ...
>
> Applications can generate notifications by issuing a HTTP POST request
> to the /user_id/notifications Graph API, with a **app access_token**.